# Primefaces Lifecycle component is not working with Myfaces

Tags: primefaces, myfaces, wildfly-11

Recently we have migrated from Mojarra 2.2.15 to myfaces 2.2.11 version and found that Primefaces Lifecycle component is not working.

Note: We are using Wildfly 11

we have added following content in faces-config.xml

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>org.primefaces.component.lifecycle.LifecyclePhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

[image: Phase Listener]

Above configuration for `p:lifecycle works` fine with Mojarra but same is not working with Myfaces. How to solve this issue.

Comment: define 'is not working'. What did you debug... Breakpoints? etc...

Comment: Lifecycle component is not updating time taken for each phase( restore view takes 30 ms,etc). In Mojarra Lifecycle, component will get updated on every request but same is not updating in Myfaces.

Comment: So if you look at the http network traffic, each 'update' response from the server is identical to the previous one regarding this component and consequently 'not updating'? Again, what did you debug? Is the phaselistener called? Etc...Investigate as a developer, not an end-user.